# MySQL join query on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

**user** table:

```
id  groupid username
1   1   user1 
2   1   user2
3   2   user3
4   2   user4
```

**group** table:

```
id  groupname
1   group1
2   group2
3   group3
```

**sales** table:

```
id  userid  amount 
1   1   10
2   1   15
3   1   30
4   3   10
5   3   25
```

I like to know how many rows in sales table by groupid, not by userid. But sales table has no groupid field.
How can I join these 3 tables to get what I want? is this possible with one join query?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51800706/2469308 - if it works for you, please upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) between the three tables based on the (foreign) key relationship between them, and use `WHERE` condition of groupid, to get results only for a specific `$groupid`

```
SELECT sales.* FROM sales 
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = sales.userid 
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user.groupid 
WHERE group.id = $groupid;
```

**EDIT:**
As asked further in the comments, to get Sum of sales for a particular `groupid`, we use [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp) function. Here is the updated query:

```
SELECT SUM(sales.amount) AS total_sales  FROM sales 
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = sales.userid 
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user.groupid 
WHERE group.id = $groupid;
```

Comment: Thanks... one more.. how can I get the sum of amount in sales table by group?

Comment: @user1942626 can you please upvote and accept the answer ! I am modifying the answer to give you sum flexibility also

Answer (score 0):

You can just join two tables to get what you want:

```
select u.groupid, count(*) as count, sum(s.amount) as total
  from user u
  join sales s on s.userid = u.id
  group by u.groupid;
```